# How does MQTT persistence session work for clients without public IP?

Tags: mqtt, iot

I wonder how the persistence session works for MQTT clients without public IP, particularly those IoT devices with NB-IoT sim card.
For example, I have device A subscribed to Topic-X. I wonder how does the broker relay the message of Topic-X to device A.

1. First, even broker having device A IP address does not help, since it's not public.
2. Is there some kid of tunnel maintained btw device A and broker after A's successful subscription? Does it need the help of networking routers for maintaining that tunnel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no link between session persistence and a clients IP (public or otherwise).

When a client connects it identifies itself with a [Client Identifier](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901059) and the server will use this to link the connection to a session as per [the spec](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Session_State):

> In order to implement QoS 1 and QoS 2 protocol flows the Client and Server need to associate state with the **Client Identifier**, this is referred to as the Session State.

Note that connections are always established by the client (the server will never attempt to connect to a client). The server will (subject to subscriptions and settings like ["Session Expiry Interval"](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901048)) store messages whilst the connection is down (these messages will be transmitted when/if the client reconnects - again subject to things like ["Clean Start"](https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901039)).

Comment: For my application, I have a Python client (A) that runs in the same machines as the broker and subscribes to some specific topic. I want to use it to record all the messages of that topic into database. What I have observed is that every time after a remote client successfully publishes a message to the broker, the callback function of A is triggered. It seems to me that client A's connection to broker is always there. I wonder if the connection maintenance is done by the Python MQTT library.

Comment: There are multiple python libraries so difficult to confirm ([paho](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#loop-forever) certainly provides reconnect functionality). Note that the TCP connection may remain live for a long time (so reconnects may not be needed often).